# Detect account switching in Phantom Wallet?

Tags: phantom, nextjs

What is the best way to detect account switching in Phantom Wallet?
I am using Nextjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: [establishing-a-connection#changing-accounts](https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/extension-and-in-app-browser-web-apps/establishing-a-connection#changing-accounts)

There are different methods to detect the provider.

```
provider.on('accountChanged', (publicKey) => {
    if (publicKey) {
        // Set new public key and continue as usual
        console.log(`Switched to account ${publicKey.toBase58()}`);
    } 
});
```